# return updated models in mongoose using updateMany?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

this is my code:

```
const result = await Todo.updateMany(
      { _id: { $in: ids }, userId },
      { $set: { complete } },
      { new: true }
    ).populate('userId', '_id');
res.json({ todos: result })
```

it works on updating data but it returns this:

```
{ n: 1,
  nModified: 1,
   opTime:
    { ts:
       Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1543568180 },
      t: 1 },
   electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000001,
   ok: 1,
   operationTime:
    Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1543568180 },
   '$clusterTime':
    { clusterTime:
       Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1543568180 },
      signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] } } }
```

how can i return the updated models?

Comment: `updateMany` operation doesn't have `new: true` option and even it doesn't return the updated document. If you need to get the updated documents you need to use `update` or `findOneandUpdate` command with map over the `ids`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to update multiple documents and return all updated documents.

`update()` or `updateMany()` method updates multiple documents and returns only the [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#writeresult)

---

You can have updated document in response if the single document gets updated using `findAndModify()` of MongoDB method using `{new: true}`.

From the documentation.

> **[findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)** : The findAndModify command modifies and returns a single
>   document. By default, the returned document does not include the
>   modifications made on the update. To return the document with the
>   modifications made on the update, use the new option.

**What you can do is:**

Fetch again those documents which are updated.

```
const result = await Todo.updateMany(
      { _id: { $in: ids }, userId },
      { $set: { complete } },
      { new: true }
    ).populate('userId', '_id');

// here you can update and then get all documents again
const updatedResult = await Todo.find(
      { _id: { $in: ids }, userId }
    ).populate('userId', '_id');

res.json({ todos: updatedResult });
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to say that you can't return all updated documents using `updateMany`.

Comment: hello, i am new in mongoose, what method do you think i should use to achieve returning those updated models?

Answer (score 0):

Update query only returns the update information like the number of records, the number of records updated, operation time, status etc.

If you want to returns record then you need to use

```
findAndModify()
```

[Mongodb findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

Also, you can use save(), it will update the document if present else creates the new document. But save() allow one record at a time. So for that, you need to use loop to update multiple records.

[Mongode save()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/)